# Carregar uma pagina a partir de uma string html

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf

Estou com a seguinte duvida que, acredito que embora seja besta, está me dando um belo de um trabalho.

Seguinte, tenho uma variável do tipo `string` e preciso realizar um método que vai receber este código e exibir a pagina em uma nova aba. Estava utilizando a biblioteca `SelectPdf` para converter essa `string` em um PDF porém ao utilizar com o azure ela não funciona então to perdidasso aqui. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejamos, você poderia criar um arquivo HTML tendo por base sua string usando a classe IO, que a pegaria e transformaria em um arquivo, e escrevê-lo no mesmo local onde se encontra sua aplicação. Depois era só abri-lo usando o:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://seu_site_aqui");

E só. Já fiz isso muitas vezes.

Vejamos, percebi que você não entendeu muito bem o que quero dizer, então demonstrarei com esse pseudocódigo:

```
string suaString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>";
StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(@"...\paginaQueDesejo.html");
escritor.WriteLine(suaString);
escritor.Close();

// Pronto, sua pagina foi criada e está pronta para ser exibida, agora é só exibí-la.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"...\paginaQueDesejo.html");
```

Somente isso, não sei se isso resolverá seu problema, mas na maioria dos casos esta é uma solução simples e eficiente.

Comment: Não é uma pagina, a pagina(código html) esta dentro de uma variável do tipo string e é ela que quero carregar em uma pagina. Em outras palavras quero renderizar minha variável em uma pagina nova

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa abrir uma página web a partir de um link na sua aplicação?

Se for isso, tente:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://seu_site_aqui");
```

Para abrir em nova aba, você pode usar o atributo `target=_blank` em um link simples, por exemplo:

```
<a href="http://seu_site_aqui" target="_blank" >Clique aqui</a>
```

Comment: não é uma pagina, a pagina(código html) esta dentro de uma variável do tipo string e é ela que quero carregar em uma pagina. Em outras palavras quero renderizar minha variável em uma pagina nova

Comment: @user24203 ainda bem que você não gostou dessa gambiarra :)

Comment: você quer simular o comportamento de um <iframe> do HTML, então? Apresentar o conteúdo de uma página html dentro de outra?

Comment: Sim isto mesmo, mas não necessariamente pois vou abrir em uma nova janela não na atual a página